# Creating a new class in iOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi, I'm new to the iOS app development I have created an app with two `ViewController` for the the second controller have created on class in called video controll view. Everything is fine but when I click the play I'm getting warning like this I don't what is this can anyone please help me on that I'm stuck here for long time.

```
2013-12-25 10:10:12.890 politicalapp[346:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

This is the code I have put for the video player:

```
- (IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"d" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL: url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;[player.moviePlayer play];
    player = Nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: You're passing a nil string to initFileURLWithPath: You need to show the code where you call that method.

Comment: @user3133826 reason: ' -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' ** First please check your string is null or not..? or put the code here for understanding ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `pathForResource` is returning nil. There can be a number of causes of this. Try changing it to:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"d.mp4" ofType:nil]];
```

If that doesn't solve it, just search the multiple of questions on stackoverflow named "Path for resource returns nil" and trouble shoot based on the various issues already discussed.